# Please explain this behavior of fgets() in C

Tags: c, fgets

To my understanding, `fgets()` will scan for input until a carriage return(`\n`), but my this code shows otherwise. I do not know where the extra line come from. Can someone explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SZ 256

void reverse(char str[]) {
    /* fill in the function body please */
    for (int i = 0, j = strlen(str) - 1; i < strlen(str) / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        char temp; // perform the swap
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    char mesg[BUF_SZ];
    printf("Enter a message please=> ");
    fgets(mesg,BUF_SZ,stdin);
    reverse(mesg);
    printf("%s\n",mesg);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: And here are a few ways to [remove the newline from fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got an input of "Hello" followed by a newline. You reversed it, to get a newline followed by "Hello". Then you printed that out, followed by a newline.

```
fgets(mesg,BUF_SZ,stdin);
```

Okay, so now we have "Hello" followed by a newline.

```
reverse(mesg);
```

Okay, so now we have a newline followed by "olleH".

```
printf("%s\n",mesg);
```

And we output that, followed by another newline.

What's the mystery?

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid now. Haha. Thanks a lot. Guys, your carriage return is scaned with fgets() too

Answer (score 2):

From [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) documentation, it keeps the carriage return `\n` in the input:

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character array pointed to by str. Reading stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case **str will contain that newline character**. If no errors occur, writes a null character at the position immediately after the last character written to str.

So,

```
"Hello\n"
```

becomes:

```
"\nelloH"
```

That's what you are getting!